# How to use user input in prolog to search

Tags: variables, testing, input, prolog

hello i want to be able to get the user input then store it and use in in my code.

```
    body(mercury, 36, small, none, none).
    body(venus, 67, small, atmosphere, none).
    body(earth, 93, small, atmosphere, none).
    body(moon, 93, small, none, none).
    body(mars, 141, small, atmosphere, none).
    body(jupiter, 489, large, atmosphere, rings).


    miles(Body,Miles):-write('Enter the Goal State:'),nl,
           read(X),nl,
           body(Body, Miles, _, _, _); Miles > X.
```

Comment: miles:-write('Enter the Goal State:'),nl,
           read(X),nl,
           body(Body, Miles, _, _, _); Miles > X. 

does not work!!

Comment: Are you aware of what `;` does in Prolog?

Comment: You should get out your Prolog textbook, or google and try some tutorials if you're just guessing. `;` acts as a disjunction. Prolog will execute the queries, `read(X),nl,
           body(Body, Miles, _, _, _)` and the query `Miles > X` separately as a disjunction. The whole query succeeds if either of them succeeds.

Comment: ok i fixed that. it was a error on my part.  my problem is when i run this
miles(Body,Miles).
i only get back one answer if i enter 10 i should get back all the facts, but i am not getting them

Comment: That seems to be an odd behavior of SWI Prolog. In GNU Prolog (which is what I use), it will prompt all of the correct solutions. If you change it to `miles(Body, Miles, X) :-...` and get rid of the `write` and `read` stuff, it will work with query `miles(Body, Miles, 10).`. BTW, you should edit your question and change the code to what you have it updated to. Otherwise, it will not be correct for other watchers.

Answer (score 0):

i switched to GNU prolog firstly which helped.

```
     miles(Body,Miles):-write('Enter the Goal State:'),nl,
                      read(X),nl,
                      body(Body, Miles, _, _, _), Miles > X.
```

Comment: See [this post and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329006/a-difference-in-swi-prolog-versus-gnu-prolog-behavior).