# SWI Prolog backtracking behavior after `read/1` call

Tags: prolog

I was looking at [another Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317413/how-to-use-user-input-in-prolog-to-search) question on StackOverflow and encountered this situation.

Suppose I have the following facts:

```
foo(1).
foo(2).
foo(3).
foo(4).
```

At the SWI Prolog (version 7.4.2) prompt, I exercised this:

```
2 ?- write('Enter number: '), read(X), nl, foo(Y), Y > X.
Enter number: 1.

X = 1,
Y = 2.

3 ?-
```

As you can see, SWI Prolog provides one solution with no prompt for additional solutions (which do exist). It does not backtrack.

In GNU Prolog (version 1.4.4), the behavior is more what I would expect:

```
| ?- write('Enter number: '), read(X), nl, foo(Y), Y > X.
Enter number: 1.

X = 1
Y = 2 ? ;

X = 1
Y = 3 ? ;

X = 1
Y = 4

yes
| ?-
```

---

Thanks to @trivelt for a reduction of the problem to simply:

```
?- foo(X).           % Backtracks and finds all solutions for X
?- read(_), foo(X).  % Does not backtrack and finds only one solution for X
```

---

Is this a bug in the SWI version 7.4.2 implementation? Or are these alternative acceptable/expected behaviors?

Comment: Your problem can be even simplified to `read(_), foo(X).`. When we remove `read`, it will compute all possible answers. It's interesting, but unfortunately I don't know the reason of this strange behaviour.

Comment: SWI version 6.6.6 behaves like GNU Prolog

Comment: @gusbro interesting. So they possibly broke something in a subsequent release. It seems like a fundamental scenario, so a little surprising it sneaked past.

Comment: @trivelt Thanks for the simplification. I was mimicking the original problem that brought it to my attention, but I'll add your comment to the post since it is a nice reduction of the issue.

Comment: Just for the record: Yap 6.2.2 also behaves like GNU Prolog with both, the original example and the simplification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least, I would regard it as a **severe deficit** of the SWI toplevel that an interaction with a *program* may interfere in this unexpected way with the *toplevel control*.

In SWI-Prolog, this is filed as **issue #166**:

[**Using read/1 on the toplevel commits unexpectedly**](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/166)

This shortcoming of the SWI toplevel prevents users to see all solutions in many cases of practical relevance.

Since ECLiPSe has already fixed this issue, maybe someone will fix it in SWI too at some point.

Comment: Thanks, this basically answer the question, which was whether it was officially considered a bug and not an acceptable "alternative behavior" (although such a thing would be weird). I should have searched the SWI issue database.